# Select2 doesn't show selected value

Tags: jquery-select2

Select2 loads all items from my list successful, the issue I found when try to select a specific value when page loads. Example:

:: put select2 in a specific html element, no value is selected even all items are loaded.

```
$('#my_id').select2();
```

:: When the page is loaded I'm trying to show a specific item selected, but doesn't work as expected, because even selected, the select2 doesn't show it.

```
$('#my_id').val('3'); //select the right option, but doesn't render it on page loads.
```

How to make a selected option to pop up when pages loads?

Thanks in advance.

#UPDATED

:: How I load all select2 items (sorry, its jade, not pure HTML):

```
label(for='category') Category
    span.required *
select(id='category', style='width:230px', name='category')
    option(value='') - Select -
    each cat in categories
        option(value='#{cat.id}') #{cat.description}
```

P.S.: All items from my list are loaded.

:: How I initialize the select2:

Just put the following line code on my javascript and it does successful:

```
$('#category').select2();
```

:: How I'm trying to select a specific value:

- First attempt:

  ```
    $('#category').select2(
        {
            initSelection: function(element, callback) {
                callback($('#field-category').val());
            }
        }
    );
  ```
- Second attempt:

  ```
    $('#category').val($('#field-category').val());
  ```

P.S.: `#field-category` has a value its a hidden input field and works OK.

Comment: Is "3" the value for the option that you want to select? Have you wrapped the code in a document ready function?

Comment: Can you share the mark up/data for the select2

Comment: @Ito See my updated answer, looks like no need to use `initSelection`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to use the [initSelection](https://select2.org/advanced/default-adapters/data#initselection) option to set the initial value.

If you are using a pre-defined `select` element to create the select2, you can use the following method

```
$('select').select2().select2('val','3')
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AeXYN/)

Comment: I've tried initSelection before, maybe my code is wrong. I'll show here

Comment: Thanks Arun, worked for me. When page loads, select2 is loaded with a specific value.

Comment: Nice code, btw I want to understand why I have to use select2() twice?

Comment: It is because, I didn't find a way to pass the initial value to the `select2`. so I'm creating the `select2` using the first call and then set the value using the second call.

Comment: Thanks, Arun, maybe it's a bug from the component.

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you maybe help with the [initial selection in BackboneForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634267/how-to-initialize-the-selection-for-rails-select2-in-backboneforms-schemata)?

Comment: @ArunPJohny Please correct me if I'm wrong. I tried the fiddle example using your link but it doesn't seem to work, the default value there should be Three right ? but it shows always One.

Comment: @guilhebl see now - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AeXYN/ - the plugin js files was relocated so there were errors

Comment: This is now deprecated in favor [of the other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26857096/359284) in Select2 4.0.0 and will likely stop working entirely in Select2 4.1.0.

Answer (score 37):

add a trigger change after setting val:

```
$('#my_id').val('3').trigger('change');
```

Comment: This is now the recommended way of setting the value in 4.0.0, as it works consistently and matches a normal `<select>`.

Comment: What if I don't want to trigger change and still have it show?

Comment: But what if I've attached something to "select2:select" and not change? Doing the above doesnt work.

Answer (score 5):

A very simple way to tackle this problem is :

```
//Step1: Here assuming id of your selectbox is my_id, so this will add selected attribute to 1st option
$('#my_id option').eq(0).prop('selected',true);

//Step2: Now reinitialize your select box

//This will work, if you haven't initialized selectbox
$('#my_id').select2();
```

or

```
//This will work, if you have initialized selectbox earlier, so destroy it first and initialise it
$('#my_id').select2('destroy').select2();
```

Answer (score 5):

This may help:

```
$('#mySelect2').val('1'); // Select the option with a value of '1'
$('#mySelect2').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed
```

You can find more on details [here](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items):

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `select2 v4.0.0` or above, you can check [select2 documentation](https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items)

```
// Initialize select2 for all select tags
$('select').select2();

// Initialize select2 for a specific id
$('#my-id').select2();

// Initialize select2 for a class
$('.my-class').select2();

// Update the displayed value after changing the selected option.
$('#my-id').trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. Actually what worked is triggering the change event here.

$('#my-id').trigger('change');

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to make `val` in select2 just select the corresponding element.
For some reason, select2 doesn't provide the function to look up selections by id.

init:

```
$("#thing").select2({data:sources, initSelection: function(item, callback) {
  // despite select2 having already read the whole sources list when you 
  // do .val(n) you have to explicitly tell it how to find that item again.
  var to_be_selected = null;
  $.each(sources, function(index, thing) {
    if (thing.id == item.val()) {
      to_be_selected = thing;
      return;
    }
  })
  callback(to_be_selected);
}})
```

normal code

```
// to load the thing with id==3 from the initial sources list.
$("#thing").select2({'val': 3})
```

Comment: maybe it's `{val:3}` not `{'val', 3}` ?

Comment: `{val: 3}` (not a real option) and `{val, 3}` (invalid syntax) won't actually work. You might get lucky if Select2 reinitializes itself, but that's a lucky side effect in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Per [here](https://select2.github.io/options.html#initSelection) initSelection is deprecated in Select2 4.0 and later.

Using Select2 4.0.0 this worked for me:

```
$('#my_id').select2({val:3});
```

HT: @Kokizzu

Comment: `val` isn't even a valid option for Select2, this works because calling `.select2()` completely re-initializes Select2 (which ends up detecting the new selected value).

Answer (score 0):

I meet with the same problem, this works for me：

```
Using Select2 > 4.0.0
$('#select_id').val('3').trigger('change');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I was sending selected in the data set still default option was not getting selected. I had to do something like below to make it work -

```
$(".select").select2({
    data: data_names
});
data_names.forEach(function(name) {
    if (name.selected) {
        $(".select").select2('val', name.id);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a multiple select2 box with multiple selections.

Step 1 was to put my string of school_ids into an array of integers corresponding to the id of each school, and remove a leading zero. I had to do this in a separate script tag.

```
<script>
    var school_ids = <%= raw JSON.parse(@search.school_ids).map{|x| x.to_i} - [0]%>
</script>
```

Step two was to create the select box, then set the values, then trigger like so:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.select2-multiple').select2({
            placeholder: "Hit Enter After Selection",
            width: 'resolve'
        });
        $('.select2-multiple').val(school_ids);
        $('.select2-multiple').trigger('change');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

trigger just select2 to set the value

```
$('#my_id').val('3').trigger("change.select2");
```

and this will trigger select2 with dropdown

```
$('#my_id').val('3').trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var option=$(this);
   if(option.val()==data.StudentCourses.CourseId)
   {
    option.setAttribute('Selected');
   }
   });
```

i have initilized select2 because i just want few options selected from them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $('.classname').each(function() {
     $(this).siblings().find('.select2selection__rendered').text($(this).text())
    })
```

in my case I were dealing with a class then I used this way to set showing content at select2

```
  <option selected value="your_value">your_text</option>
```

u need to put this at each select box's   first option