# Select2 default selected option

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 to **show options from a json array**.
How can I **set default selected option** ?
I tried using **initSelection**, but it was of no help.

Comment: Can you post the code you've written so far?

Comment: In your select box, can you simply add the attribute "value = 'the_value_you_want'"?

Comment: Following this link to get the answer :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957419/select2-doesnt-show-selected-value