# Asp.NET Web Api retrieving Data in AJAX not displaying in dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api, jquery-select2

I have a problem displaying a dropdownlist that I retrieved from my WEB API, it is working fine the item is selected but the problem is it's not appearing in the dropdown?

In this example the Id is pointed to Management please look at the screenshot because the has selected Management but it's not displaying
[Click here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SpVA1.png)

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownList("DropdownInterest", 
    (SelectList)ViewData["InterestList"], "",
    new { @class = "form-control select2" }
)
```

**Web Api**

```
     //
    // GET : api/UserInterest/GetInterestListbyId/{id}
    [HttpGet]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    [Route("api/UserInterest/GetInterestListbyId/{id}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetInterestListbyId(string id)
    {
        Binder b = new Binder();
        AreaofInterest ai = new AreaofInterest();
        FieldInterest fi = new FieldInterest();
        var readUserInterest =  fi.Read()
                                .OrderBy(x => x.Interest)
                                .ToList()
                                .Join(ai.Read(),
                                 f => f._Id,
                                 a => a.FieldId,
                                 (field, area) => new
                                 {
                                     // New Anonymous Fields
                                     AreaIds = area._Id,
                                     ProfileIds = area.ProfileId,
                                     Interest = field.Interest
                                 })
                                 .Where(x => x.ProfileIds == id);


        if (readUserInterest != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, readUserInterest);
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Error 404: Not Found");
        }

    }
```

**Controller**

```
  public async Task<ActionResult>  Auto()
    {

        Binder b = new Binder();

        using (var http = new HttpClient())
        {
            http.BaseAddress = new Uri(upi.baseUrl);

            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage getInterest = await http.GetAsync(uai.getFieldofInterest);



            if (  getInterest.IsSuccessStatusCode )
            {

                // Get Field of Interest
                var responseInterest = getInterest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                b.fiList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FieldofInterest>>(responseInterest);
            }
        }

        // Dropdown Section

        ViewData["InterestList"] = new SelectList(b.fiList, "_Id", "Interest");
        return View();
    }
```

**Javascript Ajax call**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/api/UserInterest/GetInterestbyId/88ef622b-ae9e-48d9-ad9f-617749bc4ae7',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) { 
                $('#uai1__Id').val(data._Id); 
                $('#DropdownInterest').val(data.FieldId);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. You mean "Management" is not appearing on the editable field when selected?

Comment: Yes Management is not appearing in the dropdownlist

Comment: have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957419/select2-doesnt-show-selected-value

Comment: it didn't work :(