# Load value from dropdown menu on GET

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I've inherited a CRUD UI  - it's built in ASP.NET with C#, JavaScript (jQuery 3.3.1) and SQL Server 2017.

When I got it, an input form field for Country was free text, and I wanted to make it a dropdown, which I did, using Select2 (https://select2.org). For creating a new record in the database, all is working as expected.  However, when I do a `GET` to load a record into the UI, the Country dropdown just displays its blank value ("Choose Country") as opposed to the Country associated with the record.  I'm not sure if I'm missing some JavaScript, or HTML, or both.

Here is the code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select class="js-example-basic-single" name="country" id="country">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose Country</option>
        <option value="Country1">Country 1</option>
        <option value="Country2">Country 2</option>
        <option value="Country3">Country 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:** (a profile is a record)

```
// Load profile
    $('#btnSearch').click(async function () {
        var profileField = $('#profile_id').val();
        if (profileField == "") return;
        var profileId = parseInt(profileField);
        $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", true);
        var profile = await getProfile(profileId);
        console.log(profile);
        if (profile.success == false) {
            var modal = $('#errorModal');
            modal.find('h4').html("A problem occurred...");
            modal.find('p').html(profile.error);
            modal.modal('open');
            return;
        }
        $('#name').val(profile.name);
        $('#country').val(profile.country);
        M.updateTextFields();
        $('.form').find(':input').prop("disabled", false);
    });

// Get Profile - invoked by Load Profile
    async function getProfile(profileId) {
        var response = await fetch(`${endpoint}api/profile?id=${profileId}`, {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            cache: 'no-cache',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            }
        });
        var profile = await response.json();
        return profile;
    }
```

I don't think the C# Controller methods are relevant here, but if someone would like to see them, please let me know and I will post them.

What code am I missing?

Comment: The Select2 documentation examples all seem to invoke the `change` event after setting values, which in this case would look like `$('#country').val(profile.country).trigger('change')` - have you tried that?

Comment: I did review the documentation but I'm not sure that I fully followed that.  I will try it now.

Comment: It's here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items#selecting-options  *When you make any external changes that need to be reflected in Select2 (such as changing the value), you should trigger this event.*

Comment: Note that select2 changed substantially for v4 - the accepted answer is for an old version, but there is an answer for v4: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26857096/2181514

Comment: So I tried `$('#country').val(profile.country).trigger('change')` per @user7290573 and that also matches up to the v4 answer from freedomn-m's linked thread - it did SOMETHING, but not what I need - now it shows a blank field, as opposed to showing "Choose Country." Any thoughts on that?

Comment: What's the value of `profile.country`? What happens if you try manually setting a value (e.g. `$('#country').val('Country1').trigger('change')`)?

Comment: Good suggestion @user7290573 - you're on to something there.  I got it to populate by doing `$('#country').val('Country1').trigger('change')`  Now debugging to try to figure out why that works and `profile.country` does not.